# Nested calls to the python interpreter

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ program which calls some python function (using PyRun_StringFlags). At some point this python script calls back the C++ code. I'd like to call some python functions as well. So a backtrace looks like:

```
Py  Test::p() // Here I do a print "hello world"
C++ PyObject_CallMethod()
Py  PyRun_StringFlags()
C++ main()
```

But the test I did with a very simple "print" in the Test::p function doesn't indicate that it works. Is it because I'm using the python interpreter while it's still being used?
Python cannot create separate interpreters so I have no idea what to do, since what I need is essentially to execute a completely unrelated Python script.

Comment: Ops! It turns out that PyObject_CallMethod returns NULL, how can I further debug this fact?